How to pass data between sibling Livewire components within the same parent component?
I have a Livewire application with three components arranged in the following hierarchy:

Parent Component: MapContainer
Child Component 1: GeoJsonViewer
Child Component 2: GeoJsonSearch

I am trying to send data from GeoJsonViewer to GeoJsonSearch. Both components are included in the same parent (MapContainer). Below is the structure of my components:
Parent Component (MapContainer)
This parent component renders both GeoJsonViewer and GeoJsonSearch components.
<!-- resources/views/livewire/maps/map-container.blade.php -->

<div>
    <livewire:geo-json-viewer geoJsonUrl="https://example.com/data.geojson" />
    <livewire:geo-json-search />
</div>

Child Component 1 (GeoJsonViewer)
This component initializes the map and attempts to dispatch an event that should be received by GeoJsonSearch.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Maps;

use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class GeoJsonViewer extends Component
{
    public $geoJsonUrl = "https://example.com/data.geojson"; 
    public $layerId = "geojson-layer";
    public $mapInstance;

    #[On('mapInitialized')]
    public function handleMapInitialized($mapId)
    {
        $this->mapInstance = $mapId; // Assign the map ID to the instance property

        // Dispatch an event to send GeoJSON data to the sibling component
        $this->dispatch('loadGeoJson', [
            'geoJsonUrl' => $this->geoJsonUrl,
            'layerId' => $this->layerId,
            'mapId' => $mapId,
        ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.maps.geo-json-viewer');
    }
}

Child Component 2 (GeoJsonSearch)
This component is supposed to listen for the loadGeoJson event and receive the data, but the $geoJsonUrl value is always null.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Maps;

use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class GeoJsonSearch extends Component
{
    public $searchQuery;
    public $searchResults = [];

    #[On('loadGeoJson')]
    public function loadData($geoJsonUrl, $layerId, $mapId)
    {
        // The $geoJsonUrl value is always null here
        dd($geoJsonUrl);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.maps.geo-json-search');
    }
}

Problem:

I want to send the geoJsonUrl from GeoJsonViewer to GeoJsonSearch using the event loadGeoJson. However, when loadData is triggered in GeoJsonSearch, the $geoJsonUrl parameter is always null.
Both components are siblings in the same parent component (MapContainer).

What I Have Tried:

I used the dispatch method to send the event from GeoJsonViewer to GeoJsonSearch.
I verified that MapContainer is correctly rendering both components in the same view.
I added an event listener using #[On('loadGeoJson')] in GeoJsonSearch.

Questions:

Why is the $geoJsonUrl parameter not being passed correctly to GeoJsonSearch?
What is the correct way to communicate between sibling components in Livewire that are rendered within the same parent component?
Is there a better approach to sharing data between these two components?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:

I am using Livewire 3.x with PHP 8.x.
The components are set up with #[On('event')] attributes to listen for specific events.


The problem is the way the parameters are passed in the dispatch of the loadGeoJson event: on the PHP side (unlike Javascript) the parameters of dispatch() must be passed individually:
$this->dispatch('loadGeoJson', $this->geoJsonUrl, $this->layerId, mapId);

Using PHP 8 you can also use named arguments:
$this->dispatch('loadGeoJson', geoJsonUrl: $this->geoJsonUrl, layerId: $this->layerId, mapId: $mapId);

